# How do you add a space after the keyword "function" - JS Beautify

Tags: js-beautify

trying to make it so that the package picks up this:

```
function(){}
```

and corrects it to:

```
function () {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line in the js block of your *.jsbeautifyrc* file

```
    "space_after_anon_function": true
```